# Getting a matrix of values from a Matrix with names and list with values

Tags: r

I have a character matrix M1 with names and a named list L1 with values.

I want to create a matrix M2 with values, the same size as M1. For each cell in M2, there should be the value that in L1 corresponds to the name in M1. Cells in which M1's name is not in L1, M2 should be NA.

I tried to do so but hadn't managed to.

Here's an example of what I'd want to do.

```
>M1
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] 
[1,] "n1" "n4" "n7" "n10"
[2,] "n2" "n5" "n8" "n11"
[3,] "n3" "n6" "n9" "n12"

> L1
$n1
[1] 1

$n2
[1] 2

$n8
[1] 3

$n25
[1] 4
```

From there M2 should end up being:

```
> M2
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1   NA   NA   NA
[2,]    2   NA    3   NA
[3,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

Reproducible Examples,

```
dput(m1)
structure(c("n1", "n2", "n3", "n4", "n5", "n6", "n7", "n8", "n9", 
"n10", "n11", "n12"), .Dim = 3:4)

dput(L1)
structure(list(n1 = 1, n2 = 2, n8 = 3, n25 = 4), .Names = c("n1", 
"n2", "n8", "n25"))
```

Comment: Can you please make reproducible examples? It'd be easier to help you.

Comment: M1 and L1 are the data I have. It's basically like in the example: Some strings in M1. The names in L1 correspond to the strings in M1 (though some are there are some aren't). I don't quite understand how I could help you making it easier. Some random function that generates M1 and L1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to `unlist` `L1` and match the names with each element of the matrix

```
apply(m1, 1:2, function(i) unlist(L1)[match(i, names(L1))])

#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    1   NA   NA   NA
#[2,]    2   NA    3   NA
#[3,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

Answer (score -4):

We can also do this by `match`ing the 'm1' with `names` of 'L1' to get the index and use that to replace with 'L1', and change the dimensions

```
`dim<-`(unlist(L1)[match(m1, names(L1))], dim(m1))
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    1   NA   NA   NA
#[2,]    2   NA    3   NA
#[3,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
```